# Web Server send data along with file

Tags: dart

I'd like to serve an html page *as well as* some json to the client without a round-trip that can be processed on the client side. Is this possible? What's the best way of doing this? I've considered sending it in the header but it seems to be frowned upon by some. Any examples are greatly appreciated. Psuedo code:

```dart
main(){
  ...
  app.addRequestHandler((req) => req.path == '/user', handler);
}

void handler(req, res) {
  var file = new File(myHtmlFile);
  res.headers.set(...); //add json here?
  res.outputstream...   //or here?
  ...
  stream.pipe(res.outputStream);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your html file you can put a *tag* to be replace before sending as response.

For instance, in your html file :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
  <input type='hidden' id='datas' value="___JSON_DATAS___"/>
  ...
</body>
</html>
```

`___JSON_DATAS___` will be replace in your server with something like :

```dart
void handler(req, res) {
  var file = new File(myHtmlFile);
  readStreamAsString(file.openInputStream()).then((fileContent) {
    final content = fileContent
        .replaceAll("___JSON_DATAS___", htmlEscape(jsonAsString));
    res.outputStream.writeAsString(content);
    res.outputStream.close();
  });
}

String htmlEscape(String text) {
  return text.replaceAll("&", "&amp;")
      .replaceAll("<", "&lt;")
      .replaceAll(">", "&gt;")
      .replaceAll('"', "&quot;")
      .replaceAll("'", "&apos;");
}

Future<String> readStreamAsString(InputStream stream) {
  final completer = new Completer();
  final sb = new StringBuffer();
  final sis = new StringInputStream(stream);
  sis
    ..onData = () { sb.add(sis.read()); }
    ..onClosed = () { completer.complete(sb.toString()); }
    ..onError = (e) { completer.completeException(e); };
  return completer.future;
}
```

Then, on client side :

```dart
import 'dart:html';
import 'dart:json';

main(){
  final input = query('#datas') as InputElement;
  final datas = JSON.parse(input.value);
  //...
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for! Thanks. Would be great if this was built into the language at some point. Server side templates that the client can interact with.